# Legacy servers to Azure environment migration

Tags: windows, azure, server, migration, cloud

Hope you are doing well.

We are a small business and we are now looking to migrate our current 8 virtual machines to our new azure sub the problem we having is that our servers are Win servers 2008 and 2012r2 we want to have Win server 2019 on Azure as our new OS but Azure migrate can only migrate as is :(

So I know we could upgrade our on-prem servers to 2019 but that will be a lot of pain is there any other possible way?

We have our payroll and database on both these servers so if we did new create new VMs in Azure how could we copy over this data and apps without Azure migration?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scenario where you can leverage the power of the cloud to test your upgrade.  I think there is the ability to do an in-place upgrade of Win 2008 to 2019 but it takes two (2) in-place upgrades.  The first will go from 2008 -> 2012 and then you can do a 2012 -> 2019.  This in theory should work.

I would suggest migrating your server as-is to Azure then you can 'test' the in place upgrades.  These new servers in Azure should be on a private Vnet as to not interfere with the 'production' systems on prem.  Once in Azure, you can snapshot them and test as many times as needed the in-place upgrades.  Once you are satisfied with the results you can restore the original snapshots to a production Vnet and do the in-place upgrades that you tested.